# Does std::list in C++ have a find( ) method?

Tags: c++

So I created an array of lists of arrays:

```
list<string> myArrayOfLists[size];
```

Then I pushed a word into it like this:

```
myArrayOfLists[index].push_back(word);
```

Then I tried to find a word like this:

```
myArrayofLists[index].find(myArrayOfLists[size].begin(), myArrayOfLists[size].begin(), word);
```

That last command returned a error that said:

```
no member named 'find' in 'std::list<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char>>>'
```

I thought that if I imported `<algorithm>` so why am I still getting an error? Is there another way to search the list and find what I am looking for?

Comment: _"So I created an array of lists of arrays"_ No you didn't.

Comment: Please read the [tag:STL]  tag wiki before using that tag or acronym next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Whoops! You forgot to [*read the documentation*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). There is no member function `find` in `std::list`.

Instead, use the generic [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) from the header `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Ya I tried `string x = find(myArrayOfLists[size].begin(), myArrayOfLists[size].begin(), word);` but I get the same error message.

Comment: @IsabelAlphonse Read carefully the documentation of `std::find`. It returns an iterator, not a value. So you have to test it first, then dereference the iterator.

Comment: Since I can't use anything in C++ 11 is there a way to tell if the element exists in the list without using the `auto` type?

Comment: @IsabelAlphonse `std::list<std::string>::iterator it = std::find(...)`.

Comment: The documentation tells you the return type.

Answer (score 2):

Only those standard library containers which can somehow find elements *efficiently* have `find` member functions. For all other containers, use the `std::find` free function:

```
auto it = std::find(x.begin(), x.end(), "needle");

std::cout << (it == x.end() ? "not found" : "found");
```

Comment: I find it delightfully ironic that an explicitly "non-efficient" function is "free" :)

Comment: I hope that with the introduction of ranges the `std::find` will be able to delegate to the member function `find` in case the latter exists.

Comment: Since that returns the iterator and not the actual value is there any other way of searching through a linked list? Can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: @IsabelAlphonse `*it` is the value. That's how the algorithms in the Standard Library work, they are glued to the data structures via iterators.

Comment: @IsabelAlphonse: Well, since you *searched* for the value, the value you found is just the value you searched for... (but you can of course dereference the iterator).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's not so much "non-efficient" as it is just a "linear search". Some containers can look elements up faster than linearly; for all others, linear search *is* the most efficient way of locating an element.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It was a joke.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I know :-) I just wanted to make sure nobody comes across this comment and thinks less of the free function.